# Is there a C# case insensitive equals operator?

Tags: c#, .net, string, operators, case-insensitive

I know that the following is case sensitive:

```
if (StringA == StringB) {
```

So is there an operator which will compare two strings in an insensitive manner?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Caselessly comparing strings in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501906/caselessly-comparing-strings-in-c-sharp)

Comment: In case someone stumbles across this question looking for a case insensitive comparison for a Dictionary<string,int>, have a look at this question here: [Case insensitive access for generic dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230414/case-insensitive-access-for-generic-dictionary)

Comment: It would be really nice; say to define a corresponding `~=` to parallel `==` as a case-insensitive version.

Comment: If Microsoft developers see this, I think there is a need for a case-insensitive operator in the next version of csharp. This string.Equal() is lengthy.

Answer (score 318, accepted):

Try this:

```
string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I'm a relative StackOverflow newbie -- can you explain what you mean by adding a link? Do you mean to the MSDN docs?

Comment: You can add an MSDN link (which I usually do) or if you find any interesting blog posts or such that maybe expand the answer.

Comment: And you could enrich your answer by trying to get close to what the asker wanted. In this case, you could post a quick extension method.

Comment: Such as: public static bool EqualsCaseInsensitive(this string a, string b) { return string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase); }

Comment: If you want culture sensitive comparison, use this method. If you just want to make sure "FILE" and "file" are both accepted, use "OrdinalIgnoreCase" or your code might not work in places like Turkish locales. For more info, see http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html

Comment: Argh this is such an awful mouthful! my keyboard will wear out. Gone are the days when I can use "`if A$=B$ then goto 10`"

Comment: @Sanjay Manohar Then write a custom operator - and I'd recommend a better keyboard.

Comment: The extension method is nice, but be aware that LINQ will not expand the extension method and will throw an error if used in a LINQ expression.

Comment: @Sako73 if your default collation in SQL is not a binary one then anytime your LINQ needs to be expanded it is already being evaluated case insensitively. String == string is evaluated by SQL rules not .Net.

Comment: May be worth noting that String with a capital S.

String.Equals(string, string, StringComparison)

Comment: or:  a.Equals(b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

Answer (score 54):

**The best way** to compare 2 strings ignoring the case of the letters is to use the [String.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx) static method specifying an ordinal ignore case string comparison. This is also the fastest way, much faster than converting the strings to lower or upper case and comparing them after that.

I tested the performance of both approaches and the ordinal ignore case string comparison was **more than 9 times faster**! It is also more reliable than converting strings to lower or upper case (check out the Turkish i problem). So always use the [String.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx) method to compare strings for equality:

```
String.Equals(string1, string2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

If you want to perform a culture specific string comparison you can use the following code:

```
String.Equals(string1, string2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Please note that the second example uses the the string comparison logic of the current culture, which makes it slower than the "ordinal ignore case" comparison in the first example, so if you don't need any culture specific string comparison logic and you are after maximum performance, use the "ordinal ignore case" comparison.

For more information, [read the full story on my blog](http://www.pvladov.com/2012/09/case-insensitive-string-comparison.html).

Comment: Don't suggest `ToLower` or `ToLowerInvariant`: they create memory just to perform a comparison, and they may fail as new character sets are added to unicode. `ToUpper` fails because of the Turkish 'i', among others; there's no reason why `ToLower` won't fail in the future for similar reasons.

Comment: @antiduh, thank you for your comment. Most of us are aware of these potential problems, many tutorials over the Internet give the Turkish 'i' as an example. As you see in my post, I do not recommend using `ToLower` or `ToLowerInvariant` methods, I just wanted to show how much more efficient the `String.Equals` method is.

Comment: "Most of us are aware of these potential problems, many tutorials over the Internet give the Turkish 'i' as an example" - not enough people are, and you're still mentioning it as the second sentence in your answer. Furthermore, your *answer* does not include enough justification to never use it - you simply mention performance; performance is not always the ultimate priority. As a result, you're currently violating the help center guidelines; links to external sites are fine, but you've not summarized the content sufficiently (turkish 'i' problem). SO is not your advertising platform.

Answer (score 20):

There are a number of properties on the `StringComparer` static class that return comparers for any type of case-sensitivity you might want:

[`StringComparer` Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer_properties.aspx)

For instance, you can call

```
StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(string1, string2)
```

or

```
StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Compare(string1, string2)
```

It's a bit cleaner than the `string.Equals` or `string.Compare` overloads that take a [`StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) argument.

Answer (score 14):

```
System.Collections.CaseInsensitiveComparer
```

or

```
System.StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
```

Comment: Does this effect the entire application?

Comment: Where can I find more info on this. Does this mean I can use == for a case insensitive match?

Answer (score 9):

```
string.Equals(StringA, StringB, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 8):

or

```
if (StringA.Equals(StringB, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
```

but you need to be sure that StringA is not null. So probably better tu use:

```
string.Equals(StringA , StringB, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

as John suggested

EDIT: corrected the bug

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
if (stringA.equals(StringB, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 3):

Operator? NO, but I think you can change your culture so that string comparison is not case-sensitive.

```
// you'll want to change this...
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
// and you'll want to custimize this
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CompareInfo
```

I'm confident that it will change the way that strings are being compared by the equals operator.

Comment: Yeah, to say the very least it's utterly not what you would want to do unless you want all string comparisons to be case insensitive. But I think it changes the behavior of the equals operator.

Answer (score 3):

Here an idea to simplify the syntax:

```
public class IgnoreCase
{
    private readonly string _value;

    public IgnoreCase(string s)
    {
        _value = s;
    }

    protected bool Equals(IgnoreCase other)
    {
        return this == other;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj != null &&
               (ReferenceEquals(this, obj) || (obj.GetType() == GetType() && this == (IgnoreCase) obj));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _value?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(IgnoreCase a, IgnoreCase b)
    {
        return string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(IgnoreCase a, IgnoreCase b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(IgnoreCase s)
    {
        return s._value;
    }

    public static implicit operator IgnoreCase(string s)
    {
        return new IgnoreCase(s);
    }
}
```

Usable like:

```
Console.WriteLine((IgnoreCase) "a" == "b"); // false
Console.WriteLine((IgnoreCase) "abc" == "abC"); // true
Console.WriteLine((IgnoreCase) "Abc" == "aBc"); // true
Console.WriteLine((IgnoreCase) "ABC" == "ABC"); // true
```

Comment: While I like the clean **looking** usage syntax, it is a bit misleading (`IgnoreCase` vs `IgnoreCaseString`) and ambiguous (Java picks implicit unboxing vs implicit boxing so I _believe_ this wouldn't work in Java with the implicit cast back to string in there). And this creates the memory overhead of 2 new objects with the call tree execution for each comparison jumping into several nested method calls for the displayed usage case. That said, for most cases the performance is probably good enough.

Comment: While this is a _clever_ idea, it isn't really wise from a maintainability perspective. You are effectively creating a surrogate string type instead of using the system's built-in string type. The programmer-that-comes-after won't understand what's going on at a glance and then he/she will cuss at you. Using string.Equals() isn't really all that bad and most people will understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

I am so used to typing at the end of these comparison methods: `, StringComparison.`

**So I made an extension.**

```
namespace System
{   public static class StringExtension
    {
        public static bool Equals(this string thisString, string compareString,
             StringComparison stringComparison)
        {
            return string.Equals(thisString, compareString, stringComparison);
        }
    }
}
```

Just note that you will need to check for null on `thisString` prior to calling the ext.

Comment: Is this the same as this built-in method in current .NET Framework versions? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_StringComparison_

Comment: Appears so. Looks like the later versions of .net include this now.

Comment: Available since .NET 4.5 and all .NET Core versions.

Comment: They're not entirely compatible because the extension method works even when thisString is null, while the built-in one would throw NPE.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Compare(string1, string2, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Others answer are totally valid here, but somehow it takes some time to type `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` and also using `String.Compare`.

I've coded simple String extension method, where you could specify if comparison is case sensitive or case senseless with boolean - see following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49208128/2338477

Answer (score -1):

```
if (StringA.ToUpperInvariant() == StringB.ToUpperInvariant()) {
```

People report ToUpperInvariant() is faster than ToLowerInvariant().

Comment: Invariant might be a bad idea if the current or desired culture has special rules for upper-casing.

Comment: Does this create a new copy of each string?  If so, bad idea.

Comment: This will also throw an exception if either (or both) strings are null.

Comment: Performance-wise, this is not such a good solution as you will create 2 new string instances here as well.

Comment: as mentioned in multiple comments - don't change the string to upper/lower to compare. just use the existing overload of String.Equals that takes the StringCompare parameter. Your option will be significantly less performant.