# How to test two strings for ordinal case-insensitive equality using TStringHelper?

Tags: delphi, string-comparison, delphi-xe7

I might have overlooked something, but it seems that there is no built-in function like:

```
var
  B: Boolean;
  S: string;
begin
  S := 'Test';
  B := S.SameText('TEST');
  Assert(B);
end;
```

.NET has a [three parameter version for Equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631233/is-there-a-c-sharp-case-insensitive-equals-operator):

```
string.Equals(S, "TEST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

The two versions I can come up with is:

```
// Ordinal?
string.CompareText(S, 'TEST') = 0
// Culture specific
string.Compare(S, 'TEST', True, TLanguages.UserDefaultLocale)
```

What puts me off here is that I have to compare to 0, instead of good old `SameText`:

```
SameText(S, 'TEST')
```

Did Embarcadero overlook to provide a `SameText` on `TStringHelper`?

Comment: Maybe it's okay to just use the 'old' SameText function?

Comment: `TStringHelper`'s got a *pure* `CompareOrdinal` method http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.CompareOrdinal

Comment: @fant Yes, but it does not behave as SameText does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Did Embarcadero overlook to provide a SameText on TStringHelper?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

AnsiCompareText - Compares strings based on the current locale without case sensitivity.