# How NOT to check capital letters in strings c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm trying to create a (Pokemon) project just for fun. My friend tried it and he said that the moves' name shouldn't be checked so strictly. Now it's like:

```
string Movename = "Dark Pulse";
string ChosenMovename = Console.ReadLine();

if (Movename == ChosenMovename)
{
    Console.WriteLine(...);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Didn't you mistype something?");
    goto P1; //P1 is the end of the code -> the program closes
}
```

He said I should use an array for different ways of typing like `Dark Pulse`, `dark pulse`,`Dark pulse`,`dark Pulse`,`DARK PULSE` (I hope you see the difference). And you know if he writes down `dark pulse` then `(Movename == ChosenMovename)` will be false because "Dark Pulse" and "dark pulse" are not the same. So, how NOT to check capital letters in strings?

Comment: It this a console application? Can you use numbers instead?

Comment: `string.Equals` with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Comment: `string.Equals(Movename, ChosenMovename, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: If the code is expecting an input from a finite known list of possible inputs, consider providing the user with a means of selecting from that list instead of blindly typing it.  This provides a friendlier user experience while reducing the potential for typos in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Convert both strings to upper (or lower) case in the comparison.

```
if (Movename.ToUpper() == ChosenMovename.ToUpper())
```

Or, as the others have pointed out, use the built-in case insensitive string comparison function:

```
if (string.Equals(Movename, ChosenMovename, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: This is not recommended because it causes unnecessary allocations. Furthermore, this is not the fastest way. And it is culture-dependent.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12349602/2598770 - the proposed duplicate

Comment: And may still encounter e.g. the Turkish "I" issue.

Comment: You're right, but I doubt either are a problem in this case.