# Case Sensitivity on Decide Shapes in BizTalk 2013R2

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Diagnosing an issue with a BizTalk app where part of it's logic doesn't seem to be triggering.

Currently it's designed to use a Decision Shape to filter on 2 values from a specific message.

One of those values is the word 'staff' in lower case, whereas the map that constructs the message uses a string functoid to populate the value as 'Staff' (sentence case).

I'd test this to see if it's the cause, but we don't currently have a test environment, and there's about 8 apps that this is a dependency on, so I'd need to go through a convoluted process of taking them all offline and deploying the small fix at a gamble.

On that basis, would anyone know; Is BizTalk Decide Shape Expression logic case sensitive?

Comment: You don't have a development environment where you can test it?

Comment: Historically no, and not by my choosing (relatively new to the organisation). It's something I'm currently building a proposal for.

Comment: Well this incident is a classic example of why you NEED development and test environments, so you can 1) diagnose the issue 2) test the fix.  I will test this scenario for you and let you know

Comment: Cheers mate, appreciate that. Already have this scenario down as a key example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the decide shape is case sensitive.

I tested with a rule

```
Message(FILE.ReceivedFileName) == "D:\\in\\YES.xml"
```

I dropped through a files YES.xml, yes.xml and YES.XML, and only the YES.xml went through the Rule branch, the other files went through the Else.

This is probably due to C# being case sensitive, see [Is there a C# case insensitive equals operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631233/is-there-a-c-sharp-case-insensitive-equals-operator)

Comment: Thanks again, appreciate you going out of the way to confirm