# I have to compare case sensitivity of word in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

```
db.tbluser.Where(c => c.Email == objUser.Email && c.Code.Equals(objUser.Code, StringComparison.Ordinal)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Specifically, when i match email and password both at same time it do not match password case sensitivity.
I am using this query but it is not comparing case sensitivity of word.
I want to compare LHR5P with lhr5p.
It should not get value against this.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631233/is-there-a-c-sharp-case-insensitive-equals-operator

Comment: How about using `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` instead of `StringComparison.Ordinal`? [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=net-5.0) should help as to why the `Ordinal` wont work.

Comment: This looks like Entity Framework to me? If so, the normal C# methods won't work.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate since that seems to be the problem here, though you haven't really given enough information. The dupe is quite old but has essentially the same answer.

Comment: i have to match case sensitivity. It do not match like this
db.tbluser.Where(c => c.Code == objUser.Code).FirstOrDefault();

e.g

PASSworD with PaSSwoRd

Comment: More specifically, when i match email and password both at same time it do not match password case sensitivity. 
i have to match case sensitivity. It do not match like this db.tbluser.Where(c => c.Email == objUser.Email && c.Code == objUser.Code).FirstOrDefault(); e.g PASSworD with PaSSwoRd

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be case sensitive just do:

```
db.tbluser.Where(c => c.Code == objUser.Code).FirstOrDefault();
```

Else if you want it insensitive just:

```
db.tbluser.Where(c => c.Code.ToLower() == objUser.Code.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
```