# Accept Uppercase and Lowercase as True in C#

Tags: c#

I want my code to detect my input even if it's Uppercase or Lowercase as true but I don't know how to, someone help me, thanks, here's some examples if you guys are confused:

Input:
`y or Y`

Output:
`True`

Code:

```
string start = "y";
// I want y to be detected as true even if the input is uppercase Y
if (Console.Readline == start) {
    Console.WriteLine("True");
}
```

Searched online, not sure if I scoured enough but I didn't see anything, also I'm a beginner so if the solution is simple please don't get mad at me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a C# case insensitive equals operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/631233/11683)

Comment: use `String.ToUpper()` function for checking