# How to ignore Cases in C#

Tags: c#, compare, string-comparison

I have this code right here, and I'm trying to search a name in the contacts independently if my input is upper case or lower case (e.g. Search for the contact "John" independently if I input "john"/"John"/"jOhn"/etc) but I have no clue how to do that.

```
using System;
namespace Exercise_8._5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[,] sContacts = new string [5,2];
            string sSearch = "";
            int iRows = 5;
            int iSub = 0;

            ReadContacts(ref sContacts, iRows);
            Search(ref sSearch, iSub);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void Contacts(ref string[,] psContacts)
        {
            psContacts[0, 0] = "John";
            psContacts[0, 1] = "07621456900";
            psContacts[1, 0] = "Jasper";
            psContacts[1, 1] = "07843456377";
            psContacts[2, 0] = "Jane";
            psContacts[2, 1] = "07935254678";
            psContacts[3, 0] = "Jim";
            psContacts[3, 1] = "07945112623";
            psContacts[4, 0] = "Jackie";
            psContacts[4, 1] = "07431733507";
        }
        static void ReadContacts(ref string[,] psContacts, int piRows)
        {
            Contacts(ref psContacts);

            Console.WriteLine("My top 5 Contacts are: ");
            Console.WriteLine();

            for (piRows = 0; piRows < psContacts.GetLength(0); piRows++)
            {
                Console.Write(psContacts[piRows, 0] + " - ");
                Console.WriteLine(psContacts[piRows, 1]);
            }
        }
        static void Name(ref string psSearch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Search: ");
            psSearch = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void Search(ref string psSearch, int piSub)
        {
            int piRows = 5;
            int piColoumns = 2;
            string[,] psContacts = new string[piRows, piColoumns];

            Contacts(ref psContacts);
            Name(ref psSearch);

            while (piSub < psContacts.GetLength(0) && psSearch != psContacts[piSub, 0])
            {
                String.Compare(psSearch, psContacts[piSub, 0], true);
                piSub++;
            }

            if (piSub != psContacts.GetLength(0))
            {
                for(piRows = 0; piRows < 5;  piRows++)
                {
                    if (psSearch == psContacts[piRows, 0])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.Write(psContacts[piRows, 0] + " - ");
                        Console.WriteLine(psContacts[piRows, 1]);
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                for(piSub = 0; piSub < 1; piSub++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(psSearch + " doesn't exist");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say you don't know how to do it, yet you have the line `String.Compare(psSearch, psContacts[piSub, 0], true);` which does just that... (I didn't read the whole code, but [that's what that overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-5.0#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_) does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caselessly comparing strings in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501906/caselessly-comparing-strings-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Someone told me about this - String.Compare(psSearch, psContacts[piSub, 0], true); - and I decided to try it, but its not doing anything, I'm still not able to search in in other ways. I don't know if I am placing it in a bad place or if I am supposed to write it in another function and read all the contacts and the input of the user and compare them. I have tried different other methods that I saw in the internet but none of them are working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
string val = "AStringValue";

if (val.Equals("astringvalue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

or

[Compare(String, String, Boolean)](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_)

By the way you have this method implemented in your code as far as i see.

Answer (score 0):

I add this answer which do the same as the Ales one

By default, `string.Equals` is case sensitive

```
string.Equals("A", "a")
//false
string.Equals("A", "a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
//true
```

You can use `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` to apply the end-user machine culture

Answer (score 0):

The string comparison that you're currently using *will* be case insensitive (the third parameter is `ignoreCase`):

```
String.Compare(psSearch, psContacts[piSub, 0], true)
```

However, you aren't actually using the result of the comparison. [`String.Compare(String, String, Boolean)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_) returns an `int` representing the "lexical relationship between the two comparands". So to check that the strings are identical, you would want to check that the returned `int` is 0:

```
if (String.Compare(psSearch, psContacts[piSub, 0], true) == 0)
```

It's not easy to understand where exactly this `if` condition needs to be in your code for this to work. Regardless, wherever the string comparison needs to be, you should be checking the result of `String.Compare()`.